# Is cross-validation a type of stratification?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I am wondering if cross-validation is a type of stratification.

Answer (score 1):

Although both stratification and cross-validation consist of separating a single big group into several smaller ones, their goals and reasons for doing it are different (and even oppose each-other). So **Cross-validation is not a type of stratification**.

With **stratification** we want to create specialized sub-groups, each consisting of relatively similar elements which can than be processed in a more custom-fitted approach.

**Cross-validation** is a re-sampling procedure used for evaluating machine learning models on a limited data sample.

So the goal of stratification is to create groups with an inner-variance of each group being as small as possible (so that each group is specialized) and with cross-validation the goal is to get groups which have similar distributions (the elements in each group usually chosen randomly).

For example, in a case with 2 types of data that we want to divide into 2 groups, the optimal division for stratification will be:

[image]

And the optimal division for cross-validation will be:

[image]